# Django - RegexValidator using special expressions

Tags: python, regex, django, validation, django-forms

How do I implement special expressions in `RegexValidator`?

**forms.py:**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator('^[A-Za-z]+$', 'Only alphabetic')
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, validators=[alphanumeric])
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, validators=[alphanumeric])
```

I would like to use: áàäéèëíìïóòöúùüñÁÀÄÉÈËÍÌÏÓÒÖÚÙÜÑ as well but I get a *"Non-ASCII character"* error. Is there any other way to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\w` specifier, but since `RegexValidator` does not enable the `re.UNICODE` flag, you might need something like this:

```
import re
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    re_alphanumeric = re.compile('^\w+$', re.UNICODE)
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(re_alphanumeric, 'Only alphabetic')
    ...
```

**Update:** If you want to exclude numeric characters, use

```
import re
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    re_alpha = re.compile('[^\W\d_]+$', re.UNICODE)
    alpha = RegexValidator(re_alpha, 'Only alphabetic')
    ...
```

Comment: Now django does have unicode by default in regex validator